# How do you import reports into Spotfire via CLI?

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am looking into integrating our Spotfire reports into our CI process. Currently we manually export and import the reports into each environment via the Spotfire thick client.

I would prefer to control this via a batch script that would integrate with our SCM. My main issue is that I have not been able to find any information about the spotfire windows server CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/5.0.0-nov-2012/TIB_SSDoc_ServerInstallationManual.pdf there are two commands 
export‐library‐content Exports content from the library
import‐library‐content Imports content into the library

hope this helps

Comment: Excellent, this looks perfect - a parameter to the config command in TIBCO's tomcat, <installation dir>/tomcat/bin.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure i got your question but maybe that can help you https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-spotfire-automation-services-5-0-0

Comment: This looks promising - I will have to check to see if the automation services come with the server or if this is a different product. It has a CLI and can import into the Library. Looks like jobs are run based on an XML file that could be generated by SCM check-ins.

Comment: Sadly we do not have the automation services. Hopefully there is another method to import reports

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I work for TIBCO Spotfire.

The server CLI in 5.0 supports export and import of Library content. Please refer to TIBCO Spotfire Server the pages 209 and 215 in the [TIBCO Spotfire Server 5.0.1 Installation and Configuration Manual](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/5.0.1-march-2013/TIB_SSDoc_5.0.1_ServerInstallationManual.pdf).